# how drawables resources stored on device

Tags: android, resources, drawable

guys, I wonder if you put images for each density type (low/medium/high) and there are quite a few of them, won't it increase the size of application footprint on internal memory?

I would hope that android will put only needed resource file from apk to the actual application folder. Can somebody confirm that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will increase the size of the .apk, because those images need to be in the .apk.  It will not increase the RAM footprint of the app at runtime.  When an app is installed it is kept as its original .apk, so the storage space needed will be basically the size of your .apk.

Comment: so the entire apk with all the images for all densities will be on internal storage unless it was installed to SD CARD in Froyo, right?

Comment: Yes the .apk is just stored on the device as-is, either on internal storage or external storage as appropriate.